# URL to Post Meta

Tags: post-meta

I am trying to show a weblink to my WordPress users only if they are logged in. If they are logged out they will see text that says they need to "Login to View"

My Original Code

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post_id, 'external_link', true); ?>">View Website</a>
```

My Altered Code

```
    <a href="<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo get_post_meta($post_id, 'external_link', true);
} else {
    echo 'Login to View';
}
?>">View Website</a>
```

When a user is logged in, it's doing what it's supposed to but when they are logged out the url is broken. Can someone post an example of the format that it should be done?

Comment: You are trying to output _text_ of your message as the _URL_ (which it's not). I would recommend some time with PHP docs, this isn't really WP issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted:

```
 <a href="<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo get_post_meta($post_id, 'external_link', true);
    } 
    else {
        echo 'Login to View';
    }
   ?>
 ">View Website</a>
```

Is  going to echo "Login to View" as the `href` attribute.

You need something more like:

```
    <a href="<?php
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
           echo get_post_meta($post_id, 'external_link', true);
        } 
       else {
          echo wp_login_url( get_permalink() );
}
?>">View Website</a>
```

That of course won't be changing the text, just the `href`. So maybe do the conditional a step earlier (I added an arbitrary `<span>` for context):

```
<span> 
<?php 
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
   $href = esc_url( get_post_meta($post_id, 'external_link', true ) );
   $text = 'View Website'; 
}
else {
    $href = wp_login_url( get_permalink() );
    $text = 'Login to View';
}
?>
<a href="<?php echo $href; ?>" ><?php echo $text; ?></a>
</span>
```

Since you're pulling the url from the db, I wrapped it in  [esc_url() for sanitization](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#URLs).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Great to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta($post_id, 'external_link', true).'">View Website</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="'.wp_login_url(get_permalink()).'">Login to view Website</a>;
}
?>
```